# python isinstance(n, int) and int(n) == n

Tags: python

Two functions:

```
def check(n):
    if int(n) != n:
        print("int(n) != n")
    else:
        print("int(n) == n")
```

and

```
def check2(n):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        print("n is not an int")
    else:
        print("n is an int")
```

What's the difference? And which one is better?

Comment: They do completely different things, so how can one be better?

Comment: It seems I posted a stupid question. Sorry, guys.

Comment: It's not a stupid question. If you're not used to thinking in dynamic languages it's not obvious that `n` can be `None` or a `str` or pretty much anything. Maybe just delete the "And which one is better?"

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that n can be other things like "1", or {} etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is **Converting the input to `int` will fail if the input is something other than primitive data and `isinstance` will be True only when the type of input is of `int` or dervied from it.** So, its better to go with `check2`. Check the below sample runs.

```
def check(n):
    if int(n) != n:
        print("int(n) != n")
    else:
        print("int(n) == n")

def check2(n):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        print("n is not an int")
    else:
        print("n is an int")


class myInt(int):
    pass

check(1)
check("1")
#check({})      #Will throw error
#check([])      #Will throw error
check(myInt()) 
print ""
check2(1)
check2("1")
check2({})
check2(myInt())
check2([])
```

**Output**

```
int(n) == n
int(n) != n
int(n) == n

n is an int
n is not an int
n is not an int
n is an int
n is not an int
```

Answer (score 3):

The second one actually works (because it doesn't error out on something not coerceable to int), but it really depends what you want to do. If you're working in pure Python, the best thing to do is duck type - a function like this is a slight tweak on check that will check if something is an integral value (so, for example, it will work with `2.0` and also `2`, but not `'2'` but not error out:

```
def check3(n):
    "prints 'n is an int' if the value is integral"
    try:
        val = int(n)
        if val == n:
           print("n is an int")
    except ValueError:
        pass # return False would also work
    print("n is not an int")
```

In contrast, if it's important to know the difference between `1.0` and `1` (e.g., you have an int64 ndarray), then you'd want to use your instance checking `check2`, because it will let you know that it's *exactly* an int.

It boils down to this question: must it *be* an int or just *act* like an integral number? If it has to be an int, then use check2, if it has to *act* like an int, use check (but probably modify it to be within a try/except like shown above).

The other option is to take advantage of abstract base classes to allow for int-likes (for example, numpy int dtypes that are integral, but not actually subclasses of int), using an abstract base class, `numbers.Integral`.

```
def check4(n):
    if isinstance(n, (int, numbers.Integral)):
        print("n is an int")
    else:
        print("n is not an int")
```

As an aside, `check4` is *much* slower than *check3*, because the lookup for instance checking on abstract base classes involves some processing.

Answer (score 2):

Your first method, `if int(n) != n` is not a good idea.  If `n` is not a string or a number the conversion to `int` will fail with an exception:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
>>>    pass
>>> f = Foo()
>>> int(f)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
```

I believe the best way (in Python 2.x anyway) is:

```
if  isinstance(n, (int,long)):
    print 'n is an integer type'
else:
    print 'n is not an integer type'
```

Note that I am checking for `int` *or* `long`.  That's because `isinstance(0xDEADBEEF2B84F00D, int) == False`.

This code does not handle floating-point values at all. You haven't given us any information as to how this code will be used, so it's up to you to handle all cases correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Re. the first part of the question, the two functions are answering different questions. `check` is looking at the numerical value of `n` and (sort of) determining whether it has a fractional part.  `check2` is looking at the type and determining whether `n` is an integer.

- `check` makes the integer equivalent of `n` and then compares it to `n`.  So `int(1.0)==1.0` is true because `int(1.0)==1`, but int("1")=="1" is false because `int("1")==1`.
- `check2` doesn't do any conversion, but just checks to see what the type of `n` is.